# Qual é a diferença entre as keywords extends e implements em java?

Tags: java, classes

Gostaria de saber quando é que devem ser usadas e como é que podemos distingui-las. Sei que basicamente implements, significa que essa classe implementa uma classe ou um interface. E extends poderá aceder aos métodos da classe base.

Comment: `extends` serve somente para herança, quando você quer que uma determinada classe "estenda" suas funcionalidades para uma outra, de modo que ela possa usar essa funcionalidade original ou adaptar para sua necessidade. `implements` é somente para interface, pois esta funciona como um contrato, e você precisa "implementar" na classe os métodos que a interface tiver.

Comment: Só uma nota, @diegofm, para quem está criando interfaces. `extends` também pode ser usado no contexto de hierarquia de interface https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html

Comment: @diegofm, mas extends poderá ser usado tanto em uma classe derivada como uma classe base? ou apenas uma classe derivada é que poderá ter extends?

Comment: @jorgesaraiva não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: @jorgesaraiva, creio que esse artigo pode te ajudar : http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/heranca.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### `extends`

Usa-se `extends` quando você deseja aplicar herança á sua classe.

Quando falamos que a classe `A` *estende* a classe `B`, significa que `A` herda alguns (ou todos) métodos e atributos da classe `B`.

Os únicos métodos e atributos que não são herdados são os que possuem o modificador de acesso `private`.

Pode-se aplicar diversos níveis de herança. Por exemplo:

```
class A extends B { }
class B extends C { }
class C extends D { }
```

Ao fazer isso, os membros com modificador de acesso `public` das classes `D`, `C` e `B` são acessíveis na classe `A`. Os membros com modificador de acesso `protected` da classe `B` também são acessíveis na classe `A`.

Em Java é possível herdar apenas de uma classe. Não existe herança múltipla.

---

### `implements`

Usa-se `implements` quando você deseja implementar uma interface.

Não implementa-se classes. Implementa-se apenas interfaces.

Uma interface "firma um contrato" entre classes em que define comportamentos (métodos) que devem ser sobrescritos pela classe que os herda (se essa for uma classe *concreta*).

Uma interface pode conter métodos e constantes. Constantes em Java são definidas pelas palavras `static` e `final`. Ex: `public static final String NOME = "xpto";`.

Os métodos de uma interface não tem corpo. Eles tem apenas a sua definição. Ex:

```
public interface Imprimivel {
    public void imprime();
}
```

Pode-se também aplicar herança entre interfaces (exclusivamente):

```
public interface Monstro {
    public void ameacar();
}

public interface MonstroPerigoso extends Monstro {
    public void destruir();
}

public class Godzilla implements MonstroPerigoso {
    @Override
    public void ameacar() {
        //implementação
    }
    
    @Override
    public void destruir() {
        //implementação
    }
}
```

---

Vale a leitura desses capítulos da apostila da Caelum: [Herança](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/) e [Interfaces](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/interfaces/)

Comment: Só faltou citar o que foi mencionado pelo  @JeffersonQuesado, sobre interfaces tambem puderem usar extends entre si apenas.

Comment: @diegofm atualizado

Answer (score 8):

`implements` é usado quando uma classe implementa uma interface, `extends` é quando uma classe estende uma outra classe (concreta ou abstrata) ou quando uma interface estende uma outra interface. Ou seja, a keyword `extends` é usada para quando um tipo (classe ou interface) é derivado do seu mesmo tipo, e o `implements` é sempre que deseja fazer uma implementação, no caso uma classe implementa uma interface.

Possibilidades de uso das keywords:

```
class Classe {}
class SubClasse extends Classe {}

interface Interface {}
interface SubInterface extends Interface {}

class SubClasse2 implements Interface {}
class SubClasse3 extends SubClasse implements Interface {}
```

A interface nunca tem implementação portanto ela nunca pode usar o `implements`, ela só pode usar o `extends`, e ela também nunca pode derivar de uma classe, pois caso contrário estaria herdando implementações para si própria, algo que por definição não faz sentido para uma interface.

As duas keywords representam que a classe ou interface está herdando todo os métodos e atributos e consequentemente tendo acesso a eles, mas ainda existem os *modificadores de acesso* que podem por exemplo declarar métodos e atributos como `private` para que eles somente pertençam apenas a classe que o declarou.

Por a interface nunca possuir implementação não faria sentido que ela em alguma hipótese tenha um método ou atributo que somente ela use (privado), pois tudo que a interface faz é declarar métodos e atributos para que seja implementados por classes.

Exemplo:

```
interface Interface2 {
    //private int i = 0;  <<< ERRADO! apenas public, static e final são permitidos
}

class Classe2 {
    public int i = 0;
    private int j = 1;
}

class SubClasse4 extends Classe2 {
    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println(i);
        //System.out.println(j); <<< ERRADO! O atributo não está visível para a subclasse
    }
}
```